# Using .toc external files

Tags: table-of-contents, external-files

I've a two volume book and I want to put both table of contents in both books. How can I do that? My idea was to use the .toc files, but I don't know how to use external .toc file. Any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you have to *separate* `.tex` files, one for each volume? Say, `first.tex` and `second.tex`, together with `first.toc` and `second.toc`? Do you use any ToC-related packages like [`etoc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoc), say?

Comment: You can use `\makeatletter\input{volume2.toc}\makeatother` in volume1.

Comment: @Werner - Yes I've separate .tex files, and I'm not using any ToC-related package.

Comment: @HarishKumar - Thanks for the suggestion, it works.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you have two volumes `volume1.tex` and `volume2.tex` then you can use

```
\makeatletter
\input{volume2.toc}
\makeatother
```

in `volume1.tex` (at an appropriate place) to insert the toc of `volume2` in `volume1` and vice versa.