# Manual input of table of contents file (\jobname.toc) empty in some circumstances

Tags: table-of-contents, input

According to [Using .toc external files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/211419/18401), the following file should display the table of contents twice:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Contents (manual input)}
\makeatletter
\input{\jobname.toc}
\makeatother
\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\end{document}
```

but the manual input of `\jobname.toc` is empty.

If `\jobname.toc` does exist (e.g. after a first compilation of the previous `.tex` file), this manual input gives the expected (non empty) result as soon as are removed or commented:

- either `\tableofcontents`,
- or `\chapter{Foo}`.

Do you understand what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked question was about inputting a `.toc` file related to a *different* document.

At the point you use `\input{\jobname.toc}` it is surely empty, because `\tableofcontents` inputs it and then opens the file for writing onto it, thus clearing it.

The `.toc` file is then repopulated at end document.

Have a look at the `shorttoc` package that should solve your real problem.

However, it's easy to solve the problem, by delaying the opening of the file for writing at end document.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{atveryend}

\makeatletter
\def\@starttoc#1{%
  \begingroup
    \makeatletter
    \@input{\jobname.#1}%
    \if@filesw
      \AfterLastShipout{%
        \@ifundefined{tf@#1}{%
           \expandafter\newwrite\csname tf@#1\endcsname
           \immediate\openout \csname tf@#1\endcsname \jobname.#1\relax
        }{}%
      }%
    \fi
    \@nobreakfalse
  \endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Contents (manual input)}
\InputIfFileExists{\jobname.toc}{}{Missing toc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Short contents}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\end{document}
```

You see that you can input the table of contents as many times as you like; `\InputIfFileExists` should be used, because the `.toc` file might be still missing.

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27454399#27454399  I'm sure Denis will not be swayed by this desperate attempt to steal my green tick:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I'm a bit confused by the way the conversations are displayed here (not as thread) so I'm not sure I read the whole story but... I accepted your answer because, at that time, it had almost the same content as egreg's one and, if I'm right, yours was delivered before. Well, now, I must admit egreg's one is not that bad: soooooooo sorry, David! ;)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé David was much slower than me: 12 seconds.

Comment: Oh no! @egreg will be unbearable in chat now!:-)

Comment: @egreg How do you see the time to the second? When I looked at it, it was displayed only to the minute and I imagined David's answer was delivered earlier because it was displayed before yours. Now, I have to admit you deliver answers faster than your shadow (but maybe your shadow is taking his time?) ;)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé If you hover over the “answered yesterday”, you will see the exact time stamp: 18:32:44 for me, 18:32:57 for David.

Answer (score 3):

```
 \tableofcontents
```

inputs the toc but then opens it *for writing* so this deletes the original, so then you input a file while writing to it, so you are subject to operating system file buffering.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the `memoir` class (an expanded `book` and `report` class) the toc file is not deleted and repopulated until the end of the document, so you can put as many tocs as you like throughout the document.

Comment: That's currently not possible (`book` required) but your answer encourages me to have a deeper look at your class!